# Change an object list to another object

Tags: python, arrays, object

I have an array of Tag objects

```
list
[<Tag: Sport>, <Tag:Sport>]
```

and each of the Tag objects contains another object called "Blog" object.

What's the most efficient way to change the list from a Tag objects list to a Blog objects list where each Tag object entry changes to its corresponding Blog object? so that

```
list
[<Blog: ManU beats Liverpool>, <Blog: Barca or RealMadrid>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With map

```
map(lambda item: item.blog, tag_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
blog_list = [tag.blog for tag in tag_list]
```

Or to to it in place:

```
for i, tag in enumerate(tag_list):
    tag_list[i] = tag.blog
```